# Prove that Newton's method converges for x^2-p=0

Tags: newton-raphson, numerical-calculus

Given the equation $x^2-p=0, p>0$, one has to show that Newton's method will always converge for every initial value $x_0>0$.

I have found the sequence

$x_{k+1}=x_k-\frac{f(x_k)}{f'(x_k)}=x_k-\frac{x_k^2-p}{2x_k}=\frac{x_k^2+p}{2x_k}$.

The bit I'm struggling with now is to show that this sequence does indeed converge. How can I show this or is there another way to prove this task?

Comment: Look at $|x_{k+1} - \sqrt p|$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start.
The algebra to make things like this work
can sometimes be a little tricky.

$\begin{array}\\
x^2_{k+1}-p
&=\dfrac{(x_k^2+p)^2}{4x^2_k}-p\\
&=\dfrac{x_k^4+2px_k^2+p^2-4x_k^2p}{4x^2_k}\\
&=\dfrac{x_k^4-2px_k^2+p^2}{4x^2_k}\\
&=\dfrac{(x_k^2-p)^2}{4x^2_k}\\
\text{so}\\
\dfrac{x^2_{k+1}-p}{x_k^2-p}
&=\dfrac{x_k^2-p}{4x^2_k}\\
\end{array}
$

so once $x_k$ is close enough
to $\sqrt{p}$
(and I'll leave you to
come up with a
more precise estimate),
the iteration will converge.

Note that this shows,
no matter what $x_k$ is,
that $x_{k+1} > \sqrt{p}$.

Comment: You could also use $x_{k+1} \geq 1$ then $x_{k+1}^{2}-p=\frac{\left(x_{k}^{2}-p\right)^{2}}{4 x_{k}^{2}} \leq \frac{\left(x_{k}^{2}-p\right)^{2}}{4} \leq \frac{\left(x_{0}^{2}-p\right)^{2}}{4^{n+1}}$ which converges towards 0  when n is going to infinity.

Comment: You know $p > 0$, not $p > 1$.